# How to Create UITabController on a Button Click

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabcontroller

I am working on app. It has normal 3 views. On third view, I have a table view. If I select any row, I want a view which contains **UITabController**. I have created a simple UITabController app, but unable to do this. How to do this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some sample code?  It sounds like when you select the table row you want to push on your navigation controller a view controller that contains a UITabController

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your question is perhaps ill conceived.

A tab bar controller **controls view controllers**  which in turn control views. Your suggestion that a view contains a controller of controller simply does not make sense.

Maybe what you really want on selecting a row in your table view is to present a new view controller and then make the (existing) tab bar **visible**.

Answer (score 0):

You usually want a `UITabBar` to be ***THE*** navigation for your application and not show it later on one view.

But if you want to do so you should show, as Mundi said, a new `UITabBarViewController` when you select your `UITableViewCell`.

I don't know your exact usecase, but if you work with a `UITableView` I would use a `UINavigationController` to push a new View when you tap one `UITableViewCell`. Then it may be better (If you have 2-3 Elements) to use a `UISegmentedControl` in the `UINavigationBar`. This would look like [this](http://blog.episode-2.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/uisegmentedcontrol-3.jpg).